# Revoking an old oAuth 2.0 refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0

In exchange to a refresh token we get a new access token and a new refresh token. Should the old refresh token be revoked in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authorization Server should have invalidated the old refresh token on its own, no action should be required from the Client. In the specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6 it is a "MAY" for the Authorization Server:

> The authorization server MAY revoke the old refresh token after
> issuing a new refresh token to the client.

But it would be considered bad security hygiene if it didn't do so. Alternatively it could expose a token revocation API as layed out in RFC 7009 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009.